# Use Firestore Rules in Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When writing to the firestore in cloud functions we use the Admin SDK which has full read and write permissions on the firestore. But I dont wan't to implement complex user permission logic in my functions again so I would like to use the firestore rules when a user tries to write in the firestore through a Cloud Function. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to enforce the Firebase security rules while accessing Firestore through the Admin SDK. You *could* consider using the [client-side Node SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node), although I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: Ill guess I go the slightly longer way then to build the object I want to set in the cloud function, return it and then try to set it from the client side